# C++ threading - spawn an object (class) in loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I need to spawn class object. For example:

```
class Worker {
  Worker(int arg1, Object *obj);
  void workLoop() { while(true) { ... } }
}
```

And I need spawn in loop threads with creating objects. When I do this "static", it works:

```
thread th1(&Worker::workLoop, Worker(args...));
thread th2(&Worker::workLoop, Worker(other args...));
```

But I can't spawn this in loop. I tried:

```
for (...) {
  thread th(&Worker::workLoop, Worker(...));
  threadsVector.push_back(std::move(th));
}
```

...but only first thread works.

Also, I have in Worker class this:

```
std::thread spawn() {
    return std::thread(&Worker::workLoop, this);
}
```

I don't know how do this and why loop can't spawn my threads correctly.

Comment: what do you intend workLoop to do? What is its function? if it does not have to be unique to the class, I would recommend a lambda expression and pass the worker object as an argument

Comment: You're auto-initializing the thread object in the second case.   When it goes out of loop scope, it's destructed.   That terminates joinable threads.

Comment: @BadZen Shouldn't `std::move`ing the thread mean that at the time that `th` goes out of scope, it isn't attached to a thread and therefore doesn't kill the running thread?

Comment: That's not how move works.  The thread destructor still gets called, and that's what actually kills the thread.  You could make a move copy of the thread object, but that doesn't change the fact that the dtor will end the thread if joinable.

Comment: @BadZen - hm, thanks for explaination about this... I think'd that moved thread onto vector won't destruct.

Comment: @BadZen That's wildly incorrect. The destructor of `std::thread` terminates *the entire program* (via `std::terminate()`) if the thread is still joinable, and moving from a `std::thread` sets the moved-from `thread` to a default-constructed state - not joinable and not associated with any thread.

Comment: Ah @T.C., you're right.  I wasn't sure what the thread move assign and dtor actually did, so I wrote a little test to find out.  Too quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
class Worker{
   Worker(int arg, Object *obj)
   void workLoop() { while(true) { ... } }
}; // do not forget the semicolon

....

vector<thread> pool;

auto func = [](Worker w){
     w.workLoop();
};

// example with thread
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
   pool.push_back(thread(func, Worker(5, obj)));

for (int i = 0; i < pool.size(); ++i)
   pool[i].join();
// example
```

create a lambda expression that takes in a worker object and calls the workLoop method inside
then you can pass the lambda as an object and pass it an argument inside the thread constructor

Comment: Thanks, now works like a charm. I did not think about lambda.